# How to keep fields in user model in Django and add some extra field

Tags: django, django-models

I want to add some extra fields to my user model and I read custom user model with inherit from abstractuser class but when I implement user model Django username field and etc was gone.

A solution is use another model like profile but I want add extra fields to Django user model. Is this possible?

Comment: @Moon: thanks for wanting to edit here. However I rejected your proposed edit as too minor. It is better to use paragraphs (double Enter) rather than line breaks (single Enter) and, importantly, there was some voting commentary here that should have been removed. See my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom User model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Custom User Model 
    """

    TIMEZONES = tuple(zip(pytz.all_timezones, pytz.all_timezones))

    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=TIMEZONES, default="UTC")

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

You will have to register your custom model in the `settings.py` file:

```
# Registering the Custom User Model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_app.User'
```

Comment: I was thinking username field in original model has a some special validator how can I implement this?

Comment: And it has group and permission fields with linked to group and permission models is it necessary implement these fields again?

Comment: @Malekzad [Extend Django User Model](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone)